# Comparing the duplicate value in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

I have a the below portion in my VF page:

```
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! SkillReview }" var="ct" >

       <apex:column value="{! ct.Skill__c}"/>
```

And in my controller I have:

```
public List<Skill_Review__c> getSkillReview() {

    List<Skill_Review__c> results = [SELECT Id,Name,Skill__c FROM Skill_Review__c where Interview__c =:review.id];

    return results;

}
```

The result here return lot of duplicates value. I would like to display only the unique values in my VF page and not the duplicate once. How can I achieve this? Is there a way to filter out the unique values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want just unique values, consider using AggregateResult instead:

```
public AggregateResult[] getSkillReview() {
    return [SELECT Skill__c Skill FROM Skill_Review__c WHERE Interview__c = :review.Id GROUP BY Skill__c];
}
```

This will return just a unique list of values. You'll need to use dynamic Visualforce binding, since you're no longer returning Skill_Review__c objects:

```
<apex:column value="{!ct['Skill']}" />
```